# Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X Server

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

This is a bit complicated and highly specific case so I will try with a high level description and if necessary delve deeper. My purpose is to run ROS (Robot Operating System) on a Digital Ocean node so that I don't have to set it up on my Mac (anyway, it won't run properly on a Mac.)

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on the Digital Ocean node. There I am running xfce4 and tightvncserver.

On my mac, I am creating the tunnel to the above server with this command:

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l <myname> <myip>
```

On my Mac I then use `vncviewer` to connect to the Digital Ocean Server, and that seems to work fine.

When I launch the most basic ROS simulator, which normally would open a graphical window if I was running on a native ubuntu box I get this error:

[image]

Any thoughts on what is broken and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I got through this issue by lots of googling. I use this set of instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04 but instead of installing:

```
sudo apt install tightvncserver
```

I used

```
sudo apt-get install tigervnc-standalone-server
```

Which solves the immediate problem. I can run ROS, various qt utilities, and turtlesim pretty well. However, getting rviz and gazebo running breaks. I dont know if it's simply matter of performance of the particular node I have on digital ocean or something more fundamental with the configuration.

Comment: And then, to clear `No protocol specified` error, I had to `xhost + local:`